# Is it possible to syntactically search through Javascript in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-5

I'm using VSCode to work on a Javascript project.

I am using some large libraries from a third parties and code written by previous members of the team.

I am trying to understand a few things in the code that are a bit tricky. For example, I want to determine how a certain function works (i.e. `drawCurve`) and understand more about the object it belongs to (`renderer = {...}`).

The problem is that it is extremely tedious to look for the different places where `renderer` is used. When I do a standard `Find` search I get dozens of instances where the word `renderer` is used in a comment, and many times where `renderer` is part of another variable name. I would like to quickly locate all the places where the just the variable `renderer` and nothing more is used.

Does this exist with Javascript (ECMAScript 5) and/or with VS Code?

Comment: Yes, it exists in the documentation, which you should read.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through [peek feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek).

<kbd>F12</kbd> - go to definition

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> - find all references